# Minecraft server setup not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I wanted to make a server so my friends and I could play, and I am using the minecraft_server.1.11 file downloaded from https://minecraft.net/en/download/server and been using https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Configuring_from_the_command_line. I am stuck on configuring the command line because when I type in

> java -jar C:\Users\Evan\MinecraftServer\minecraft_server.1.11.jar

It says:

> 

C:\Users\Evan>java -jar C:\Users\Evan\MinecraftServer\minecraft_server.1.11.jar
[09:22:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.11
[09:22:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[09:22:25] [Server thread/INFO]: You need to agree to the EULA in order to run t
he server. Go to eula.txt for more info.
[09:22:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[09:22:25] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Stopping server
Exception in thread "Server Shutdown Thread"
C:\Users\Evan>

I have already changed the eula.txt file to 'true' and 'TRUE', so I have no idea how to troubleshoot.

Does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is probably searching in the wrong directory (`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\`), this can be fixed by calling `cd` or `chdir` (change directory).

Try this in Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`):

> cd C:\Users\Evan\MinecraftServer
>   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -jar minecraft_server.1.11.jar

EDIT: You could probably leave out the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\` bit.

Alternatively you could create a shortcut and specify the working directory (`C:\Users\Evan\MinecraftServer`).

Usually restarting your computer and just double-clicking the jar file works fine too.